# Prononcer le « e » dans « cet » — Pronouncing the "e" in "cet"

Tags: prononciation, démonstratifs, voyelles

Quand on utilise l'adjectif démonstratif *cet* (par exemple: *cet homme*, *cet appareil*), comment doit-on prononcer le voyelle *e* dans *cet* ? Comme l'*e* dans *ce*, ou comme le premier *e* dans *cette* ?

---

When we use the demonstrative adjective *cet* (for example: *cet homme*, *cet appareil*), how do we have to pronounce the vowel *e* in *cet*? Like the *e* in *ce* or like the first *e* in *cette*?

Comment: Comme un "7" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Cet*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cet#French) is pronounced /sɛt/. You can find a description and audio samples for [ɛ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) on Wikipedia.
It's the same sound as in *m**è**re*, *b**ê**te*, *f**ai**re* or *c**e**tte*.

Whereas [*ce*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ce#French) is pronounced with a milder (close to central) vowel as in *j**e***, *n**e***, *p**e**tit* or *r**e**voir*.

Comment: In most phonetically similar contexts, _cette_ is pronounced exactly the same way as _cet_ (in some contexts, for instance standalone, some speakers add a more or less pronounced schwa for _cette_).